# Fix ERROR: "operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone > integer" error

Tags: postgresql

Im trying to migrate queries from Google big query to postgresql, and Im getting this error

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone > integer

```
select *, DATE(_modification_time) as modification_date, 
       CASE WHEN t_start>0 THEN DATE(t_start) END as start_date, 
       CASE WHEN _creation_time>0 THEN DATE(_creation_time) END as creation_date, 
       CASE WHEN t_finish>0 THEN DATE(t_finish) END as finish_date, 
       'WMT' as source 
from public.set_list
```

Comment: apparently `t_start` or `_creation_time` or `t_finish` (or all three) are defined as `timestamp` columns, so you can't compare them with an integer value. What exactly are you trying to do there?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to compare a `timestamp` value with an integer (0). This is not allowed in Postgres. Instead, you can turn the timestamp into an integer by using the extract function and getting the number of seconds since the start of the Unix epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00), which is an integer, then compare that with the integer 0, like this:

```
select *, DATE(_modification_time) as modification_date, 
       CASE WHEN extract(EPOCH FROM t_start) > 0
            THEN DATE(t_start) END as start_date, 
       CASE WHEN extract(EPOCH FROM _creation_time) > 0
            THEN DATE(_creation_time) END as creation_date, 
       CASE WHEN extract(EPOCH FROM t_finish) > 0
            THEN DATE(t_finish) END as finish_date, 
       'WMT' as source 
from public.set_list
```

However, I doubt that this is what you want as it means you are comparing if any of those values `t_start`, `_creation_time` and `t_finish` is later than 1970-01-01 00:00:00. Perhaps you can share a bit more about what you are trying to accomplish here. This would help you get more focused answers.